# PHP include doesn't work in HTML

Tags: php, html

The following html does not produce any response from the included php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Here is some text. <br>
<?php include 'hello.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The hello.php file contains the ubiquitous `<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>`

Additional info:

The line of text displays properly.

PHP is installed and running properly. A call to  from within the source directory produces the expected config data.

The html document is named **test.php**

error_reporting(E_ALL); produces no additional data.

Comment: Does your html file have a `.php. extension? Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Rename your file to .php

Comment: Is your server PHP-enabled?

Comment: Guys... It says right here: "The html document is named test.php"

Comment: Are both files within the same folder?

Comment: Are you opening it using a server? Which one?

Comment: the php file you include is on the same folder level of the document one? (test.php)

Comment: Does it work if you replace `<?php include 'hello.php'; ?>` with `<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>`?

Comment: @baao not being in the same folder should give the error file not found.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
add this line as well ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: @wayzz but not a fatal error right? it isn't require but include

Comment: Which web server are you using?? Have to enabled server-includes on the server??

Comment: change include to require and see if there's a error

Comment: @MarcoMura no not fatal.

Comment: @wayzz wouldn't give one..

Comment: make sure you add this error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); to test.php and hello.php

Comment: I've tested here, and it worked fine. Appears to be something related to your config/environment/web-server.

Comment: is your web server configured for php?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1); have you added both these lines in test.php aswell?

Comment: something go wrong...

Answer (score 1):

at the end or first of your html page add this o see what is disrupting:

```
<?php error_reporting(-1); ?>
```

and this for your include:

```
<?php include("file.php"); ?>
```